# Ruby on Rails - save new record with nested association requiring this record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an issue creating a new record with nested associations in a clean way. Here's the controller code:

```
@listing = current_user.listings.build(params[:listing].permit(ATTRIBUTES_FOR_CREATE))
```

This builds an entity with several nested associations, like this:

```
class ListingDataField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  validates_presence_of :listing
end
```

However, when I do `@listing.save` in controller, I get validation errors on those nested ListingDataField entities that 'listing can't be blank'. If I understand correctly, AutosaveAssociation first validates and saves nested associations, and eventually saves top-level entity. Thus, it fails validating ListingDataField, because Listing is not yet saved.

But I believe it's right having :listing validation in ListingDataField, so I wouldn't consider removing this. I can see 2 solutions:

1. in transaction - save Listing record, then build nested associations
   one by one
2. `@listing.save(:validate => false)` but this is too ugly

Both aren't as much elegant as `current_user.listings.build(...)`, so my question is - what is the proper Rails way for this?

P.S. I searched SO for similar question but I couldn't find any, hopefully this is not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding:

```
class ListingDataField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing, inverse_of: :listing_data_fields
  validates :listing, presence: true
end
```

and

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listing_data_fields, inverse_of: :listing
end
```

This should make validation of presence work.

Comment: perfect! indeed, I missed this switch somehow